# PowerShell - can't see the member after it's added to a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add Note Property members to a file. The Add-Member command seems to run successfully but when I try to Get-Member, what I just added is nowhere to be found.

To be specific: I want to add movie information to an .avi file of a movie. Here's what I'm doing:

```
PS D:\> $x = Get-Item '.\Interstellar.avi'
PS D:\> $x

    Directory: D:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                       
-a----        11/1/2015  11:07 AM      735434752 Interstellar.avi

PS D:\> $x | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MediaType -Value "Movie"
PS D:\> $x | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition                                                                         
----                      ----------     ----------                                                                         
LinkType                  CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}
...
```

I won't paste all the members returned, but the "MediaType" member I created does not exist. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The Add-Member help file says to verify that the object is a PSObject and it is.

Edit: It seems like it only works in regular PowerShell and not in ISE. I don't know why that is But the issue's solved, sorry for the dumb mistake!

Comment: what do you get when you run `$x | gm | where-object { $_.name -eq 'MediaType'}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coming properly. Check with get-members thoroughly.

```
$x = Get-Item 'D:\Movies\mymovie.mp4'
$x | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MediaType -Value "Movie"
$x | gm
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Corresponding output]

Comment: It still wasn't working in ISE, but I just tried it in regular PowerShell and it works fine. I don't know why it wouldn't work in ISE. Thanks for your help!